How to change my font properties using c++ program including window.h file?
I want to change the font used by the console while my program is executing. I have tried using setCurrentConsoleFontEx() but it is not working as expected.
I have written the following function for this purpose:
void setConsoleFont() {
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX consoleFontInfo = { 0 };
    consoleFontInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
    consoleFontInfo.dwFontSize.X = 18;
    consoleFontInfo.dwFontSize.Y = 18;
    consoleFontInfo.FontWeight = FW_BOLD;
    consoleFontInfo.FontFamily = FF_MODERN;
    wcscpy_s(consoleFontInfo.FaceName, L"Courier Regular");
    consoleFontInfo.nFont = 0;
    HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        if (SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), true, &consoleFontInfo)) {
            cout << "Font Changed Successfuly\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "FAIL!\n";
            cout << GetLastError();
        }
}

but it is not working as expected. I was expecting that after the execution of the function, the font properties would be changed, and the everything that I send to cout after this is printed with the new font size and properties, but it does not happen. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this approach not good for what I want to achieve? Or is it not the way to do this?

Which console are you are talking about? Windows has several different ones between a cmd.exe console, Windows Terminal, powershell ...

Can you please post compilable code?

The code works in classic console but not in Terminal despite no errors. You can try debugging Terminal to see why.
